# Copy data multiple times to complete table

Tags: google-apps-script

I've developed a spreadsheet that records classroom specific data alongside student scores on the activity. The script I've written so far will copy the teacher information (name, period, assessment, and standard) as well as the standard score. That data is transferred to a data spreadsheet. I'm running up against the issue however that the teacher data is only associated with a single score entry. I need it to be associated with each score. (see poorly rendered image)

[Poorly rendered image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wTfye.png)
[Desired Outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IoyUb.png)

Subsequent saved entries fill below. This all works. I just can't get the range to fill down. Hopefully this makes sense. Code below.

```
function saveRecord() {
  
  
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  const formWS = ss.getSheetByName("Form")
  const settingsWS = ss.getSheetByName("Settings")
  const dataWS = ss.getSheetByName("Data")
  const fieldrange = ["C4","D4","E4","F4","G4"]
  const fieldvalues = fieldrange.map(f => formWS.getRange(f).getValue())
  
  dataWS.appendRow(fieldvalues)
  
  const scoresdata = formWS.getRange(13, 4, formWS.getLastRow(), 1).getValues()
  dataWS.getRange(dataWS.getLastRow(),dataWS.getLastColumn(),scoresdata.length,1).setValues(scoresdata)
  
  
  console.log(fieldvalues)
  
  
 //need to fix this, watch the video, I deleated some 
}

function clearRecord(){
  fieldrange.forEach(f => formWS.getRange(f).clearContent())
 
}
```

Comment: I still can't get what you trying to gain. Could you please to add another screenshot with desired output? (Not necessary to fill all the rows, it would be enough to add just 2-3 rows to illustrate the idea.)

Comment: I added a photo linked in the body of the original post. It's titled as Desired outcome. thanks for looking.

Comment: Hmm... Now it looks even more mysteriously to me. I see no logic. How do you know that `Teacher 2` will be on the row 17? Does the `Teacher 2` should be copied on the rows 21—31 as well?

Comment: The position of teacher 2 is dependent upon the number of scores entered by teacher 1.  The script identifies the last row of the scores and then posts the next teachers data. The purpose of this sheet is for a group of teachers to be able enter assessment data and have that data captured so that it can be reviewed at  a later date. As a result, each saved entry will populate below the previous data. The fill would need to populate between each entry.

Comment: Have tried the suggested solutions? Do you still need a help?

Comment: Neither worked unfortunately. If you have any insight, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: I just added my answer. Let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function saveRecord() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const fsh = ss.getSheetByName("Form");
  const dsh = ss.getSheetByName("Data");
  dsh.appendRow(fsh.getRange("C4:G4").getDisplayValues()[0]);
  const scores = fsh.getRange(13, 4, fsh.getLastRow()).getDisplayValues()
  dsh.getRange(dsh.getLastRow() + 1, 1, scores.length).setValues(scores)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Description**

I believe what you want is to fill in Columns A to D with the teacher info.

I'm not able to test this but I believe it will work.

I did not look at `clearRecord` because `fieldrange` is not defined.

**Script**

```
function saveRecord() {
  
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const formWS = ss.getSheetByName("Form");
  const dataWS = ss.getSheetByName("Data");
  const fieldvalues = formWS.getRange(4,3,1,5).getValues()[0];
  console.log(fieldvalues)
  
  const scoresdata = formWS.getRange(13, 4, formWS.getLastRow()-12, 1).getValues();
  scoresdata = scoresdata.map( row => fieldvalues.concat(row) );
  dataWS.getRange(dataWS.getLastRow()+1,1,scoresdata.length,scoresdata[0].length).setValues(scoresdata);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work:

```
function saveRecord() {
  
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  const formWS = ss.getSheetByName("Form")
  const settingsWS = ss.getSheetByName("Settings") // ???
  const dataWS = ss.getSheetByName("Data")
  // const fieldrange = ["C4","D4","E4","F4","G4"]
  // const fieldvalues = fieldrange.map(f => formWS.getRange(f).getValue())
  const fieldvalues = formWS.getRange('C4:G4').getValues().flat(); // it works faster
  
  const scoresdata = formWS.getRange(13, 4, formWS.getLastRow()-12, 1).getValues(); // -12 !!!

  // add the column 'filedvalues' to the 2d array 'scoresdata'
  const table = scoresdata.map(score => [...fieldvalues, score[0]])
  
  // put the the new 2d array 'table' on the sheet (after the last row)
  dataWS.getRange(dataWS.getLastRow()+1,1,table.length,table[0].length).setValues(table)
}
```

The function `clearRecord()` could look like this:

```
function clearRecord() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Form")
    .getRange('C4:G4')
    .clearContent()
}
```

Or you can just all one line at the end of the function `saveRecord()` to clear the range:

```
formWS.getRange('C4:G4').clearContent()
```

Comment: Like magic! Thank you so much! It works great! I've been fighting this script for a while now.

Comment: I'm glad if it works. But it would be great if you add comment to every answer right after you try it. Probably their authors would provide another solutions if they get feedback. And this way the future readers can see if other answers were tested.